# Are there more American houses with dogs than with children?

Tags: human-reproduction

David Brooks, in his [article](http://www.nytimes.com/2012/11/16/opinion/brooks-the-age-of-possibility.html) published today in The New York Time, has claimed "There are now more American houses with dogs than with children."

I seriously doubt this claim is true, especially after having considered that the word "child" means a person between birth and 12 year old.

So, my question is if the above claim is true or not.

Comment: __[78.2 million dogs](http://media.americanpetproducts.org/press.php?include=142818)__ Vs __[62.8 million children](https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/geos/us.html#People)__ (age: 0-14 years)

Comment: Yes @Oliver_C, but I guess that number of dogs (78,2) include also street dogs or free-ranging urban dogs. As you know they are unconfined dogs that live in street,  not in houses, and may never have had an owner.

Comment: That number is from a survey done by the _American Pet Products Association_. The survey was about  `demographics, buying habits, and other traits of U.S. owners of dogs, cats, fish, birds, equine, reptiles, and small animals`.

Comment: The measure is "number of households"; the question is asking to compare "households with dogs" vs "households with children". As it is clearly possible to have multiples of either, it may be the case that more households have children but households with dogs tend to have more dogs than households with children have children.

Comment: So what we're saying is that 100% of dog owners own dogs, but less than 100% of dog owners have children? Excellent work, Watson. Also, the claim isn't a matter of how many dogs or children live in a single house, it's a matter of how many houses have a dog or child living in it. Furthermore, a child is not restricted to age. Even if they're 25 years old, if they are living in their parents house, they're still considered a child of the household.

Comment: Dogs dont party their way out of college after spending 50k though...

Comment: What is your source for saying that the word "child" means a person between birth and 12 years old? A minor in the U.S.A. is generally a person between birth and 18 years old. That is the definition of child used for public health purposes too. Perhaps David Brooks chose that specific age range over which to make his comparison, thus motivating your definition?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

TL;DR **This is almost certainly true**

[The US department of Census reports](http://www.census.gov/compendia/statab/cats/population/households_families_group_quarters.html) in 2010 there were **35,218,000** households with "own children under 18 years" (This probably excludes some households with children, such as those being raised by someone other than the parents). This is out of a total number of households of 117,538,000.

Dog statistics are a little harder to get accurate, but The Humane Society says [39% of US households own at least one dog](http://www.humanesociety.org/issues/pet_overpopulation/facts/pet_ownership_statistics.html). That would give a number of dog-owning households at **45,839,000** - substantially more than the number of households with children. Other sources have [similar figures](http://www.americanpetproducts.org/press_industrytrends.asp).

It's probably worth mentioning that the number of households who have *ever* had children is more than the number who have children now.

Comment: Little nitpick: The 39% number from the _Humane Society_ actually comes from your _"other source"_, which is the survey done by the APPA.